# If "Strings are objects," then why can't I store properties on them?

Tags: javascript, string, object

It seems like that being true would make this possible:

```
var s = 'asdf';
s.foo = 2;

s.foo; // 2
```

But it isn't, whereas the same with functions is, as with jQuery.

Comment: Seems to be a difference of primitive strings and String objects. see [this MDN post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *everything* in javascript was an Object, then:

```
var a = new String('foo');
var b = new String('foo');

a == b; // false since objects are never equal

a.valueOf() == b.valueOf();  // true, since the values are equal
```

So for convenience there are primitives that are coerced to object where it makes sense to do so:

```
// a and b are string primitives
var a = 'foo';
var b = 'foo';

a == b;        // true, a and b treated a primitives
a.length == 3; // true, a is treated as a String ojbect
a.split('');   // ['f', 'o','o'];
```

but that coersion is only for the purpose of evaluating the expression, it does not change the value of the identifier.

Answer (score 4):

They aren't, at least not always. To quote **[MDN article on JS strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)**:

> Note that JavaScript distinguishes between String objects and
>   primitive string values. (The same is true of booleans and numbers.)
>
> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings
>   returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without
>   using the new keyword) are primitive strings. JavaScript automatically
>   converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use
>   String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a
>   method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup
>   occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and
>   call the method or perform the property lookup.